# Software testing: test remote API or just use a mock?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, tdd, integration-testing

Let say your website need to call Twitter API to perform some tasks, you have several options:

1. Only use mock
2. Use mock in unit test, but use production api in integration test
3. Only call production api, never use mock

Which one is the best approach if your services depends on the external api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would step back and ask yourself what you are trying to test.

If you are trying to test your other code in isolation, use a mock (that's the purpose of a mock after all).

If you are trying to really test end-to-end, use the production API (or a live test API if they have one).

So my answer is pretty close to your #2 choice, with the caveat that you should consider whether you need to test an API from a third party.  Sometimes it makes sense to do so or is necessary, sometimes it doesn't make sense (they are known to be reliable or it's very inconvenient to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I think the second one is the best solution. I use mocks in unit test and production api in functional tests.
I don't want the unit test use the remote api because i want them to run fast and i'm not testing the result (and connection) of that api, but I want my Jenkins fails if the api has changed or i have a connection problem or whatever

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of using Mock is for 'negative testing', e.g. how your code responds to certain error conditions returned from the API. Using Mock it is possible to test 100% of your 'reachable' code, whereas this would be problematic using a real API (in particular one provided externally to your organization).